# Get basic file permissions to compare with input in C

Tags: c, file-permissions

I need to compare a basic file permission from a file with a file permission from input. The input should be saved in `argv[1]`, and the permission information from file is stored in the classical `struct stat stat_buf`, specifically in the `stat_buf.st_mode` field.

An example of execution would be `./program 775`. Then the program must say that is the same permission of some file's `stat_buf.st_mode` inside the code. But what I know is that the format of `st_mode` is tricky because it has to be read as octal, convert it to int, and so on. How to compare without problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the format of `st_mode` is tricky because it has to be read as octal [...]

Not particularly. Just use `strtoul()` with an appropriate base (8):

```
unsigned long mode = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 8);
if (statbuf.st_mode == mode) {
    // permissions match
}
```

Comment: @AlejandroSazo Sorry, what didn't you know?

Comment: The existence of strtoul function :)

Comment: @AlejandroSazo Well, you could as well use `strtol()` (that's what you have already used anyway). `strtoul()` is nothing special, it's just for unsigned integers, so I thought it would be more appropriate. The code would work with `strtol()` too on any platform that defines `signed long` to a type that is long enough to hold an `st_mode` value. What you have to understand is that it's unnecessary to convert to decimal (why? I don't even understand) and back to octal and whatever. There's a reason `strtoul()` and `strtol()` take a conversion base argument.

Answer (score 1):

My approach was to build a function called `oct` which takes the `stat_buf.st_mode`, copies it to a buffer in octal mode, and again copies it to other buffer to eliminate the info I don't want (the first 3 numbers) and finally use the `strtol` function to get the number in decimal, to compare it with the input.

```
int oct(mode_t num) {
    int i;
    char buffer[7], buffer2[4];
    snprintf(buffer, 8, "%o", num);
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(buffer2); i++)
        buffer2[i] = buffer[i + 2];
    return strtol(buffer2, NULL, 10);
}
```

And how to test this:

```
int main() {
    int mode1, mode2;
    struct stat stat_buf;
    stat("/home/user/myfile", &stat_buf);
    mode1 = atoi(argv[1]);
    mode2 = oct(stat_buf.st_mode);
    printf("%d %d\n", mode1, mode2);
    return 0;
}
```

Example: executing `./program 775` gives as output `775 775`

Comment: If you have answered your question, (and it appears you have) click the answered button on the upper left :) so others will see clearly this is no longer open.

Comment: I can't until 2 days, I also thought it was automatic because I created this in the mode "answer your own question"

Comment: @AlejandroSazo I don't see why you did all that conversion to decimal if all you need is reading an **octal** number. See my answer.

Comment: @H2CO3 Now I remember!!! it was because the mode in octal has 6 digits, and the mode that I want to compare only has 3 digits (because is given by user) so I wanted to handle 3 digits modes

Comment: @AlejandroSazo But that 3 digits is really just saying that "all the other digits are zero". So that still doesn't explain it IMO.

Comment: I will need those numbers then to see if the file is directory or regular file